# How do you pass an array to a function using pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am trying to print an array through a function by using call by reference but keep getting a warning:

**`passing argument 1 of 'test' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`**

I tried replacing `test(&arr, n);` with `test(arr, n);`, `test(*arr, n);`, `test(&arr[], n);`, `test(*arr[], n);`, `test(&arr[], n);`

but nothing worked, what am I doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void test(int *a[], int b);
void main()
{
    int arr[]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, i, n=5;
    test(&arr, n);
}
void test(int *d[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", *d[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `arr` is nothing but `&arr[0]`. you can either do `test(&arr[0], n);` or `test(arr, n);`. As well as  `void test(int *d, int n)` or `void test(int d[], int n)`

Comment: An array, when passed to a function, becomes implicitly a pointer. This is known as the array *decaying* to a pointer, this is a term you'll often come across. This implies two things: an array function parameter is mere syntactic sugar for a pointer argument, and you do not need to take a pointer to the array to pass it to the function. As TruthSeeker said, `void test(int *d, int n)` is fine, call it with `test(arr, n)` simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you pass an array to a function

Just by using a pointer of the array element type:

```
void test(int *a, int b);
```

If you then pass an array to the function:

```
test(arr);
```

... the C compiler will pass a pointer to the first element of the array (`&(arr[0])`) to the function.

Note that you don't use the `&` in this case.

Inside the function you can use array operations:

```
void test(int * arr)
{
    arr[3] = arr[2];
}
```

(In your case: `printf("%d\n", arr[n]);`)

(This is true for any kind of pointer data type with exception of `void *`. The C compiler assumes that the pointer points to the first element of an array if you use array operations with pointer data types.)

> "passing argument 1 of 'test' from incompatible pointer type"

As far as I know, `[]` in  a function argument is not interpreted as array, but as pointer. For this reason, ...

```
void test(int *a[], int b);
```

... is interpreted as:

```
void test(int **a, int b);
```

... which means that the C compiler expects a pointer to an array of pointers (`int *`), not to an array of integers (`int`).

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler than that. In the example below I'm using `size_t` to express array size, it's an unsigned integer type specifically meant to be used for that purpose.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// you can use the size parameter as array parameter size
void test (size_t size, int arr[size]); 

int main (void) // correct form of main()
{
    int arr[]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    test(5, arr);
}

void test (size_t size, int arr[size])
{
    for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++) // declare the loop iterator inside the loop
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @rnicolas No. Study "array decay" in your favorite C beginner learning material.